# Weighted arithmetic mean

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

How can I calculate the  mean value of my graphs computed below

```
n = 0; a = 1; L = 0; m = 1/2; b = 1; g = (2 m a r)/(n + L + 1);

Fi[r_] = (r)^(L + 1) Exp[-((m a)/(n + L + 1)) r] LaguerreL[n, 2 L + 1, g];

f[r_] = AiryAi[(2 m b)^(1/3)  (r)];

Plot[{r^(L + 1) f[r], Fi[r] f[r]}, {r, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

Comment: What tables did you mean?

Comment: Is this question really about plotting so that you added the "plotting"-tag back to the question; if so you might want to edit/extend your question accordingly

Comment: @DanielLichtblau [Bobby](http://www.cmswire.com/~/media/59086df972604f35b46d0764cd0f1351.jpg)

Comment: Ah yes, little Bobby Tables and his havoc-wreaking script.

Comment: As for weighting the plots, it depends on what weights you want to use. Could do something like this for example: `w = .3;
p1[r_] := r^(L + 1) f[r]
p2[r_] := Fi[r] f[r]
Plot[{p1[r], p2[r], w*p1[r] + (1 - w)*p2[r]}, {r, 0, 6}]`

Comment: mean value for r^(L + 1) f[r] depeds on r in the interval of 0 to 6.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean)

Comment: Possibly what's wanted is `In[23]:= NIntegrate[r^(L + 1) f[r], {r, 0, 6}]/6

Out[23]= 0.0431324397654`. Anyway, voting to close. This is just way too unclear.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 0; a = 1; L = 0; m = 1/2; b = 1;
g = (2 m a r)/(n + L + 1);

Fi[r_] = (r)^(L + 1) Exp[-((m a)/(n + L + 1)) r] *
   LaguerreL[n, 2 L + 1, g];

f[r_] = AiryAi[(2 m b)^(1/3) (r)];

mu1 = Integrate[r^(L + 2) f[r], {r, 0, Infinity}]/
  Integrate[r^(L + 1) f[r], {r, 0, Infinity}]

(*  Gamma[1/3]/(3^(1/3)*Gamma[2/3])  *)

mu1 // N

(*  1.37172  *)

mu2 = Integrate[r Fi[r] f[r], {r, 0, Infinity}]/
   Integrate[Fi[r] f[r], {r, 0, Infinity}] //
  FullSimplify

(*  (9*(8*E^(1/24) - 5*ExpIntegralE[2/3, -(1/24)])*
        Gamma[5/3] + 18*3^(2/3)*(-8*E^(1/24) + 
           5*ExpIntegralE[4/3, -(1/24)])*Gamma[7/3])/
   (128*ExpIntegralE[5/3, -(1/24)]*Gamma[2/3] - 
      24*3^(2/3)*ExpIntegralE[4/3, -(1/24)]*Gamma[7/3])  *)

mu2 // N // Chop

(*  1.08475  *)

Plot[{r^(L + 1) f[r], Fi[r] f[r]}, {r, 0, 6},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 Epilog -> {
   Dashed,
   Blue,
   Line[{{mu1, 0}, {mu1, r^(L + 1) f[r] /. r -> mu1}}],
   Orange,
   Line[{{mu2, 0}, {mu2, Fi[r] f[r] /. r -> mu2}}]}]
```

[image]